# DAX column count latest record for each set of group

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to get latest record for each group in a table of rows. ex, i want **column c** like getting latest record by count

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09-11-2022 15:46:33 | 2 |
| 1 | 09-11-2022 21:16:33 | 4 |
| 1 | 09-11-2022 15:09:40 | 1 |
| 1 | 09-11-2022 20:39:40 | 3 |
| 2 | 09-11-2022 15:46:33 | 1 |
| 2 | 09-11-2022 21:16:33 | 2 |

OR

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09-11-2022 15:46:33 |  |
| 1 | 09-11-2022 21:16:33 | True |
| 1 | 09-11-2022 15:09:40 |  |
| 1 | 09-11-2022 20:39:40 |  |
| 2 | 09-11-2022 15:46:33 |  |
| 2 | 09-11-2022 21:16:33 | True |

I want to get flag for latest record in Column C. above mentioned result set i want any of it

thanks in advance

I have tried like this

```
LastById = 
Var modifiedon = 'Table' Column C
Return
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL( 'Table' ),
        'Table' Column C < modifiedon
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
Column C = 

 VAR latest = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Column B]), ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Column A]))
 RETURN IF('Table'[Column B] = latest,"true")
```

Comment: At least I got an upvote.. :) Have one too!

Comment: Great minds think alike ;)

Answer (score 4):

The first alternative:

```
Column C rank = 
RANKX ( 
    CALCULATETABLE ( 'Table' , ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Column A] )) , 
    [Column B] ,, ASC 
)
```

The second alternative:

```
Column C bool = 
VAR _max = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MAX ( 'Table'[Column B] ) , 
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Column A] ) 
    )
RETURN IF ( [Column B] = _max , "True" )
```

[image]